# Owl carousel creates empty space at the end

Tags: css, owl-carousel

I have created an owl carousel using the following settings.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({   
  autoWidth:true,
  loop:false,
  items:25,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  mergeFit:true,
  slideBy:1,
  center:false,
  dots: false,
  merge:true,
  lazyload:false,
  nav:true,     
})
```

An empty space is created at the end of my carousel.I have tried adding margin left and right to individual card items.But none seem to solve my issue.

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPRajx). We can see a empty space when we slide to the last item in the carousel.

Answer (score 1):

set autoWidth to false

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({   
  autoWidth:false,
  loop:false,
  items:25,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  mergeFit:true,
  slideBy:1,
  center:false,
  dots: false,
  merge:true,
  lazyload:false,
  nav:true,     
})
```